# Python - Can't install new packages, upgrading to TLS 1.2?

Tags: python, pip, tls1.2

I am unable to install any new Python packages using `pip`. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768770/not-able-to-install-python-packages-ssl-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version) seems to solve the issue for a lot of people, but not me. When I run

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python
```

I get

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (35) error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

Some of the other answers to that question lead me to believe I need to update TLS to version 1.2, since running

```
python2 -c "import urllib2,json; print(json.loads(urllib2.urlopen('https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check').read())['tls_version'])"
```

returns `TLS 1.0`

But I can't figure out how to do it. I'm currently using:

- MacOS 10.11
- pip 9.0.1
- Python 2.7.11
- Python 3.5.2

Any ideas?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Sorry, @Josh I'm on MacOS 10.11.  I'll update my post

Comment: @Prateek Using pip 9.0.1, Python 2.7 and Python 3.5.2.

Comment: Are you using Python 2.7.0?  The SSL versions available vary widely between versions of Python 2.7.    TLS 1.2 wasn't introduced into Python 2.7 until 2.7.9.

Comment: You are mixing pip and python versions , stick to one. use pip3 and python3 for python 3

Comment: @KevinD. 2.7.11. The .11 got deleted while I was typng

Comment: @Prateek I'm already using `pip` with `python`(2) and `pip3` with `python3`

Comment: either reinstall python or just upgrade openssl with brew command. This question seems to be duplicate as other questions have different working solutions

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49734434/unable-to-install-python-libraries#answer-49735005

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to install python libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49734434/unable-to-install-python-libraries)

Comment: @Wmbuch perhaps try to upgrade `curl` then? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46422590/1526703) similar issue about curl returning that error.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: @Ferenc I don't think I did. I can't recall what I was trying to install, but I'm guessing I just gave up